# Parallel computing using threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I do really need your help. I need to compute f(x)||g(x) using two separate threads for them in C++. Program should look like listed down below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>  
using namespace std;

int f(int x);
int g(int x);

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter an number" << endl;
    int x;
    cin >> x;

    thread first(f, x);

// Compute f(x)||g(x) using threads
// do something like this first||second

// Print result
}

int f(int x)
{
    int result = x;
    return result;
}

int g(int x)
{
    int result = x;
    return result;
}
```

If you have any idea concerning solving this problem I will really appreciate it.
Thank you!

Comment: [This stuff](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) might come in handy.

Comment: For starters: Find a way how to pass back the return value of your functions. [`std::promise()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) and [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) are a good way to do this relatively easy.

Comment: I see no atomics nor any locks. That's a *huge* red flag leading me to think that there has got to be a race condition and undefined behaviour in this code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - Why? The two threads aren't touching the same data. Not in this example anyway.

Comment: @StoryTeller not in this snippet, no. But their absence - including synchronization not being mentioned in the question at all - is *usually* a sign that the asker is not even aware of such things/issues.

Comment: Short-circuit evaluation of `||` makes the question unclear without a lot more background detail.  Performing both operations in parallel might take longer than performing just the 1st operation or even both operations sequentially.

Comment: @RichardCritten I agree. `||` could be also read as _process in parallel_ (with honestly very best will).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of problem is best solved using `std::async` and `std::future`, which can use threads or not, depending on how you use them.

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Please enter an number" << std::endl;
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    auto f_future = std::async(std::launch::async, f, x);
    auto g_future = std::async(std::launch::async, g, x);

    //will block until f's thread concludes, or until both threads conclude, depending on how f resolves
    auto result = f_future.get() || g_future.get();
    std::cout << /*...*/ << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: "Will block until both threads..." really? also if `f` returns `true` before `g` finished?

Comment: @tobi303 It will short-circuit if `f` returns `true`. I've updated the post.

Comment: ok, I really wasnt sure what happens, never (sucessfully) used futures myself. And btw I have no idea what the downvote is for